# How can I get the pre-decmial and decimal places from a Python variable of type Decimal?

Tags: python, floating-point

Let's say I've a variable `var = Decimal('3.5685')`. How can I get the pre-decimal places (`3`) and the decimal places (`5685`) from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int(var)` will give you the integer part (as an integer); from [`as_tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.as_tuple) you can get the fractional part (as a tuple):

```
from decimal import Decimal

var = Decimal('3.5685')
print(int(var))  # 3 

tpl = var.as_tuple()  # DecimalTuple(sign=0, digits=(3, 5, 6, 8, 5), exponent=-4)
print(tpl.digits[tpl.exponent:])  # (5, 6, 8, 5)
```

you may need to bring the tuple in the form you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and short solution:**

```
split = str(var).split('.')
predecimal = split[0]
postdecimal = split[1]
```

You can use the resulting variables `predecimal` and `postdecimal` however you wish.

If you want to get an integer instead of a string just split like this instead:

```
split = int(str(var).split('.'))
```